# Add / Remove css classes based on button's attribute value

Tags: jquery, css, navigation

I got a button which expands/collapses navigation menu. I need to togle button's icons from "left" arrows icon to "right" arrows icon. How can I change this navigation button's icons based on attribute value?
I wanted to achieve it with jQuery by adding / removing css classes.

```
<button class="t-Button t-Button--icon t-Button--header t-Button--headerTree" aria-label="Expand / Collapse Navigation" title="Expand / Collapse Navigation" id="t_Button_navControl" type="button" aria-controls="t_TreeNav" aria-expanded="true">
  <span class="fa-angle-double-left fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button>
```

```js
$('.t-Header-controls button').on('classChange', function() {

$('.t-Header-controls button[aria-expanded="true"]').find('span').addClass('fa fa-angle-double-left fa-2x fa-lg');
$('.t-Header-controls button[aria-expanded="false"]').find('span').addClass('fa fa-angle-double-right fa-2x fa-lg');
```

});

I need to add/remove classes to span element.
Above code is not working.
Basically when button clicked and button's attribute aria-expanded="false" I need to remove .fa-angle-double-left class and add .fa-angle-double-right class. But when button clicked again and button's attribute aria-expanded="true" then I need to remove .fa-angle-double-right class and add .fa-angle-double-left class.

I see that when Side menu is opened (expanded) then button's "area-expanded" property changes to "true":  aria-expanded="true"
At this moment I need button's icon to be "left" directional arrows - "fa-angle-double-left fa-lg" classes.

When Side menu is closed (collapsed) then button's "area-expanded" property changes to "false":  aria-expanded="false"
At this moment I need button's icon to be "right" directional arrows - "fa-angle-double-right fa-lg " classes.

Please help to find the right solution

Answer (score 1):

There is no event raised when a attribute changes. The alternative is to manually raise an event when you programatically change the attribute:

```
$('.t-Header-controls button').attr('aria-expanded','false').trigger('classChange');

// in another js file
$('.t-Header-controls button').on('classChange', function() {
    $('.t-Header-controls button[aria-expanded="true"]').find('span').addClass('fa fa-angle-double-left fa-2x fa-lg');
    $('.t-Header-controls button[aria-expanded="false"]').find('span').addClass('fa fa-angle-double-right fa-2x fa-lg');
});
```

Comment: What is .container-fluid class?
Thank you

Comment: The class of parent div, which contains the button is .t-Header-controls
Should my code be:
$('.t-Header-controls button').attr('aria-expanded','false').trigger('classChange');

Comment: also I need to add / remove classes to span element, not button itself. How do I add span to your code:
$('.container-fluid button[aria-expanded="true"]').addClass('fa-angle-double-left fa-lg');
    $('.container-fluid button[aria-expanded="false"]').addClass('fa-angle-double-right fa-lg');

Answer (score 0):

A lean way to do this would be to use [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/). Override the image url or glyph in your CSS and toggle the class on click. Add another selector to you CSS for the active class and change the image.

Example:

```html
<style>
.element {
 background-image: url(your icon);
}
.element.active {
 background-image: url(your other icon);
}
</style>
<script>
$(.element).click(function(){
 $(this).toggleClass('active');
}
</script>
```

Comment: I need to replace class when button clicked again. 
Basically when button clicked and button's attribute aria-expanded="false" I need to remove .fa-angle-double-left class and add .fa-angle-double-right class. 
But when button clicked again and button's attribute aria-expanded="true" then I need to remove .fa-angle-double-right class and add .fa-angle-double-left class. 
Thank you @britaingreen